# Spring Security 5 - how to use symmetric signingKey?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have micro-services running using old Spring Authorization Server and Resource Server (org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 deprecated now).

For new micro-service I am creating, I need to use newer version of Spring Security 5 implementation of Resource Server. (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server)

Below is code from my authorization server.

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {

  private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
  private final DataSource dataSource;
  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  private final CustomAccessTokenConverter customAccessTokenConverter;

  @Value("${signing-key:123}")
  private String signingKey;

  public AuthorizationServerConfig(
      PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
      DataSource dataSource,
      AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
      UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
      CustomAccessTokenConverter customAccessTokenConverter) {
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.customAccessTokenConverter = customAccessTokenConverter;
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    final JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    jwtAccessTokenConverter.setAccessTokenConverter(customAccessTokenConverter);
    jwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
    return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
  }

  @Bean
  public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
  }

  @Bean
  public ApprovalStore approvalStore() {
    return new JdbcApprovalStore(dataSource);
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
    return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    return defaultTokenServices;
  }

  @Bean
  public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore());
    endpoints.approvalStore(approvalStore());
    endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices());
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    endpoints.tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);
    endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  }
}
```

How do I use the symmetric signing key to decrypt JWT in Spring Security 5?

From migration guide, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide I have option to use JWT+JWK or JWT+Key but not sure what to use as my signing key is just a string.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I'm also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced exactly the same problem mentioned above. I have the old oaut2 Authorization Service and migrate the old Resource Service to Spring Security 5 standards.

So, it's my proposition of this problem. I chose  JWT + Key scenario from OAuth2 Migration Guide.

In application.yml file I added the same singleKey and additional configuration for debugging SecurityFilterChain to be able to control authorization flow according to docs:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          key-value: zSigFffuyF5CjmLAxubSTVBt5OnfbnGPkFpvNpg2n/.....

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG
```

In my configuration class, I injected singleKey by @Value annotation:

```
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.key-value}")
    private String key;
```

then I exposed default configuration on SecurityFIlterChain:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())));

        return http.build();
    }
```

and for customized JTWDecoder bean adding converting of my singleKey to SecretKey object:

```
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        byte[] secretByte = key.getBytes();
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretByte, 0, secretByte.length, "RSA");
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(secretKey).build();
    }
```

Logs withs configured debbugig:

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal - Securing GET /example_endpoint
o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate - Authenticated token
o.s.s.o.s.r.w.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal - Set SecurityContextHolder to JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@29cc3dff, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=172.16.57.7, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[SCOPE_BOU]]
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter - Secured GET /example_endpoint
```

Like in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.2/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture